# Manipulate paths with MS Windows semantics

Tags: java, windows, path

In Java, the standard library File class can be used to manipulate platform-specific paths. I have an application that will be deployed on Linux, but which needs to manipulate win32-format paths such as "C:\Path\To\File.exe" and perform operations such as obtaining the parent path "C:\Path\To\". If I use the File class, this only works if the application is also running on Windows. What alternative do I have?

Comment: File is an abstract concept of a file on the given platform, so File is not the problem, the problem is your path, you need to modify you application to, as a much as possible, work with different OS path concepts

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot use absolute windows pathes on a linux system.**
 
You should remove system dependant pathes from your code.
If you want to manipulate pathes, you can use io and/or nio API without thinking about the underlaying filesystems.

Comment: The code is intended to create scripts that will be executed on Windows systems. This answer is entirely unhelpful.

Comment: Sorry, but you could provide those essantial informations in your question to get more helpful answers.